# which method enable or disable gxt grid resize column

Tags: grid, resize, gxt

Im not been able to enable the resizing of column. It does allow to resize any one column and after that property disables. it doesnt even show the col-resize cursor.
Below is the code...

```
grid = new Grid<PolicyRowInfo>(store, cm) {
        @Override
        protected void onAfterFirstAttach() {
        super.onAfterFirstAttach();
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
        loader.load();
        }
        });
        }
        };
    grid.getView().setForceFit(true);
    grid.setLoader(loader);
    grid.setColumnReordering(true);
    ScrollingDragSource dragSource = new ScrollingDragSource(grid);
    dragSource.setGroup("top");
    panel = new FramedPanel();
    panel.setHeadingText("Header");
    panel.setCollapsible(true);
    panel.setAnimCollapse(true);
    panel.setSize("100%", "350px");
    panel.addStyleName("margin-10");
    panel.setButtonAlign(BoxLayoutPack.CENTER);
```

Comment: Your code looks similar to the Sencha GXT grid example, where everything works just fine: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:livegrid 
However, I don't know what `ScrollingDragSource` does - it's not a GXT class. Have you tried your code without it?

Comment: `ColumnnConfig.setFixed(false)` is the method used for enabling (if true) and disabling resizing of columns